# Print data in excel using java POI

Tags: java, mysql, excel, apache-poi

I am fetching data from SQL table. rows of sql table depends on ID, so here Action rows are not fixed it may vary. where as xxxx row is fixed(single row). 
I want to print output in this format in excel file

```
Column1     Column2             Column3             Column4         Column5
NAME        completedWorkflows  runningWorkflows    failedWorkflows cancelledWorkflows
xxxx        2233                1312                123             1232

ONE BLANK ROW(In below table Rows are not fixed it may change depends on data)

NAME        completedWorkflows  runningWorkflows    failedWorkflows cancelledWorkflows
Action 1    12365               54545               55              788
Action 2    54545               88                  88              4   
Action 3    97                  123                 2               87
Action 4    788                 24                  24              274
```

Below is my code. Prints values of XXXX row. Haven't code for Actions 1...4. For that need your help. Where and Which statements should I add to get above output? TIA

```
stmt = conn.createStatement();
String completedWorkflows = "Some Query";
String runningWorkflows = "Some Query";
String failedWorkflows = "Some Query";
String cancelledWorkflows = "Some Query";
String cancellingWorkflows = "Some Query";
String actionsData = "Some Query";

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(completedWorkflows);
            rs.next();
            int totalCompletedWF = rs.getInt("COMPLETED_WF");

            rs = stmt.executeQuery(runningWorkflows);
            rs.next();
            int totalRunningWF = rs.getInt("RUNNING_WF");

            rs = stmt.executeQuery(failedWorkflows);
            rs.next();
            int totalFailedWF = rs.getInt("FAILED_WF");

            rs = stmt.executeQuery(cancelledWorkflows);
            rs.next();
            int totalCancelleddWF = rs.getInt("CANCELLED_WF");

            rs = stmt.executeQuery(cancellingWorkflows);
            rs.next();
            int totalCancellingdWF = rs.getInt("CANCELLING_WF");

            // Fetching Action data. THIS QUERY RETURNS DYNAMIC NUMBER OF ROWS WITH DETAILS
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(actionsData);
            rs.next();
            String actionName = rs.getString("NAME");
            int actionWaiting = rs.getInt("WAITING");
            int actionRunning = rs.getInt("RUNNING");
            int actionFailed = rs.getInt("FAILED");
            int actionCancelled = rs.getInt("CANCELLED");
            int actionCompleted = rs.getInt("COMPLETED");

            // Excel file generation code
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Results");

            CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
            Font font = workbook.createFont();
            font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 11);
            font.setFontName(HSSFFont.FONT_ARIAL);
            font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.COLOR_NORMAL);
            font.setBold(true);
            font.setColor(HSSFColor.BLACK.index);

            style.setFont(font);
            style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.TURQUOISE.getIndex());
            style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            style.setAlignment(style.ALIGN_JUSTIFY);
            style.setBorderBottom(style.BORDER_THIN);
            style.setBorderLeft(style.BORDER_THIN);
            style.setBorderTop(style.BORDER_THIN);
            style.setWrapText(true);
            style.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);

            HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(1);
            HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
            rowhead.setRowStyle(style);

            HSSFCell cell1 = rowhead.createCell(1);
            cell1.setCellStyle(style);
            cell1.setCellValue("Completed Workflows");
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(totalCompletedWF);

            HSSFCell cell2 = rowhead.createCell(2);
            cell2.setCellStyle(style);
            cell2.setCellValue("Running Workflows");
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(totalRunningWF);

            HSSFCell cell3 = rowhead.createCell(3);
            cell3.setCellStyle(style);
            cell3.setCellValue("Failed Workflows");
            row.createCell(3).setCellValue(totalFailedWF);

            HSSFCell cell4 = rowhead.createCell(4);
            cell4.setCellStyle(style);
            cell4.setCellValue("Cancelled Workflows");
            row.createCell(4).setCellValue(totalCancelleddWF);

            HSSFCell cell5 = rowhead.createCell(5);
            cell5.setCellStyle(style);
            cell5.setCellValue("Cancelling Workflows");
            row.createCell(5).setCellValue(totalCancellingdWF);

            sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(2);
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(3);
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(4);
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(5);

            // Action results set to Excel sheet

            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation + "\\Results.xls");
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get your code to include Action 1 to 4, you need to loop through your data (the one taken using `rs = stmt.executeQuery(actionsData);`) and write it accordingly.

In this case, I suggest refactoring your code using the following guidelines:

1. Create the workbook.
2. Create the sheet.
3. Fetch your data.
4. Loop through your data (until you reach the last record).

   - While looping through your data, do the following:

     - Create a new row on the sheet.
     - Fill the cells on the created row with your data.
     - Apply your style on the cell.
5. Write your changes to the file.